# Pre fill minibuffer upon calling to helm-projectile function

Tags: helm, projectile, minibuffer

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891095/programatically-insert-text-into-command-that-normally-blocks-event-loop) answer, and its `with-initial-minibuffer` function, I am trying to call `helm-projectile-grep`, customizing minibuffer pre-filling.

I try to avoid the default behaviour, which is to pre-fill the minibuffer with the contents of the region (if active) or the thing at point.

If I use

```
(defun with-initial-minibuffer-projectile-grep (str)
  (interactive)
  (funcall `(lambda ()
              (interactive)
              (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
                  (lambda () (insert (format ": %s " ,str)))
                (call-interactively 'helm-projectile-grep)))))
```

and then I call it with

```
(with-initial-minibuffer-projectile-grep "mytext")
```

things go wrong. Any idea of where to start from ?

Comment: Helm tweaks Emacs minibuffer heavily and it is not easy change the behaviour without modifying the source code. The pre-fill input of helm is controlled by `:input` slot of  the `helm` func, `helm-projectile-grep` makes use of it in https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/1159110/helm-projectile.el#L707-L709, you can try to change code in there.

Comment: @xuchunyang Yes, I know, this is where I got stuck, but there must be a way using `noflet` or similar